# htaccess mod rewrite - half of my rules (all similar) aren't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I've been working on this all day and hoping somebody else can chime in and help me out.

I am building a new site (on our dev server) and I'm having trouble with some simple SEO friendly URLs.

I am simply redirecting some SEO friendly keywords to static PHP pages.  My file works on most links, but 2 are breaking for unknown reasons.

Here is my file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about-us$ aboutus.php [L]
RewriteRule ^resource-center$ resourcecenter.php [L]
RewriteRule ^our-services$ ourservices.php [L]
RewriteRule ^management-solutions$ ms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^additional-services$ additionalservices.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contactus.php [L]
```

For some reason, resource center and contact us are going to a 404 page.  When I click the links, a trailing slash is being added to contact-us and resource-center, but not on any of the other links.

If I edit the htaccess file and change ^resource-center$ to ^resourcecenter$, it will work fine.  If I change it to ^resource-center/$ to account for the trailing slash being added, the page will load, but none of the CSS/JS/Images are loading.

I'm stumped here, especially because it seems so inconsistent.  All of the files exist, there are no htaccess files that would be interfering, all the links in the HTML, or in the htaccess, are all formatted the same way, yet 2 of them give me errors every time.

If anybody can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Turn `MultiViews` option off
- Allow optional trailing slash

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ aboutus.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^resource-center/?$ resourcecenter.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^our-services/?$ ourservices.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^management-solutions/?$ ms.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^additional-services/?$ additionalservices.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ contactus.php [L,NC]
```

For css/js etc you can add this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from `/` and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: *removed comment* - it works after all, I had a space between the options [L,NC].  Thanks for the help!